# PyQt5 comboBox clear then addItems crashes Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Trying to remove all items in a combobox and load a new list of items after an index change from other comboboxes.  This is a very simple version of this project.  I've tried this a number of approaches. The only way I can get it to work (see the commented block) not work with the logic of the program.  The example here will crash the UI.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('a-frame.ui',self)
        self.setWindowTitle('a-frame')

        self.comboBox1.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: combobox_changed(self))
        self.comboBox2.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: combobox_changed(self)) 

# ->>> This block will crash the program
def combobox_changed(self):
    combo_a = self.comboBox1.currentIndex()
    if combo_a == 1:
        self.comboBox1.clear()
        self.comboBox1.addItems(['item1','item2'])

# ->>> This block works but it won't work cause the number of 
# indexes in the combobox vary with each choice
# def combobox_changed(self):
    # combo_a = self.comboBox1.currentIndex()
    # combo_b = self.comboBox1.currentIndex()           
        # if combo_a == 1:
            # self.comboBox1.clear()
        # elif combo_b == 0:
            # self.comboBox1.addItems(['item1', 'item2']) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app    = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The information you gave are insufficient, as the code you shared should work. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: add `self.comboBox1.blockSignals(True)` before `self.comboBox1.clear()` and add `self.comboBox1.blockSignals(False)` after `self.comboBox1.addItems(['item1','item2']`